# How to Reset the state of compose views animating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition, jetpack-compose-animation

I am building an onboarding fragment that gives users tips for each screen. there are multiple pages of a few lines:

Page 1

- this icon does this
- that icon does that

Button: Next

Page 2

- this icon does this
- that icon does that

Button: Finish

I want each view on the page to fade in progressively down the screen.

Then with a new page i want the items to reset and all fade in again from the top down.

I have tried using `AnimatedVisibility` but the problem is that elements keep their state so the fade effect doesnt play on the second page. Possibly `AnimatedVisibility` isnt the right choice for what i want to do?

So this is the code for a line. I want to reset the state object on each recomposition.

Or if someone has a better suggetion on how to do it - then that would also be excellent.

```
@Composable
    private fun Line(line: ActionResources, modifier: Modifier) {
        val state = remember {
            MutableTransitionState(false).apply {
                // Start the animation immediately.
                targetState = true
            }
        }
        AnimatedVisibility(state,
            enter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000)),
            exit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000))
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                val color = line.color?.let { colorResource(it) } ?: MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
                line.icon?.also {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(it),
                        tint = color,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.menu_search),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp).size(24.dp)
                    )
                }
                line.label?.also {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                        color = color,
                        text = it
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't compile your code especially `ActionResources`, but based on this

> I want to reset the state object on each recomposition.

I can only suggest supplying a `key` to your `remember {...}` using the the `line` parameter.

```
 val state = remember (line) {
        MutableTransitionState(false).apply {
            // Start the animation immediately.
            targetState = true
        }
  }
```

I'm not sure if this would solve your problem, but if you want this state to be `re-calculated` assuming the `line` parameter will always be different on succeeding `re-compositions`, then using it as `remember {...}'s` `key` will guarantee a `re-calculation`.